# Rtl input issue

Tags: html, css, input

Hello everybody im facing a problem in my current RTL arabic input.

```
<input type="text" name="bvalue[]" style="direction:rtl">
```

When i try to input:

```
18.9 x 65.5 x 11.6 مم
```

It doesnt show up corretly, also مم should appear on the left side not the right one.This is what i get:

```
مم 118.9 x 65.5 x 11.6
```

I didn't manage to copy the exact code because i faced the same problem on this website.How can i fix this ?

Comment: Unrelated - you can use `dir="rtl"` instead of `style="direction:rtl"`.

Comment: Which is the desired output? You can try changing [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) property, e.g. `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`.

Comment: @Oriol It works but it reverse the numbers position 1440 became 0441

Comment: Not reproduceable. Please explain exactly how you tried to input and which browser(s) you tested this on. Also note that in notations like this. you should really use the multiplication sign “×” instead of the *Latin* letter “x”.